# Undo a git commit + git branch <branchname> -- with a twist

Tags: git, git-branch, git-commit

I am in the process of "documenting in hind-sight" the history of an application development, by moving existing snapshots of the project's directory tree (that were saved back then by plain & primitive folder copies, not git or any other version control) to git.

After struggling with learning git's new concepts and new terminology, this migration process seemed to have been going well when, all of a sudden I discovered: "Oops... my last `git commit` + `git branch <branchname>` skipped one snapshot."

Since the order of committing the snapshots is important to me, I would like to completely undo the last `git commit` + `git branch <branchname>`, **as if it were never done**.

That is, "fixing by modifying a commit" as defined at the bottom of the [Undoing in Git](http://book.git-scm.com/4_undoing_in_git_-_reset,_checkout_and_revert.html) chapter in the Git book.

Everything is still local (I didn't "publish" nor did I "push" anything yet), so I believe this is in line with the warnings about "rewriting history". :)

Could you please confirm or correct the following steps required per my understanding?

1. Empty the working directory (without
   deleting the `.git` subdirectory, of
   course)
2. `git checkout <folder-name>`
   (bringing working directory back to
   the state it were immediately after
   I committed the wrong folder and
   tagged it via git branch)
3. `git branch -D
   <branchname-of-mistaken-folder-commit>`
4. `git commit --amend`

At this point I expect that git to no longer remember that the last branch and commit **have ever been done**, and the working directory contain the mistaken folder (which I will be deleting, replacing completely by the one I skipped). Is this correct?

Comment: You seem to be confusing branches and tags. If you want to create permanent tag for a commit, use `git tag`.

Comment: @svick I mistakenly committed the sin of labeling the <branchname> argument <tag> when I really meant <branchname>. Thanks +1 for pointing this out.

Comment: in that case, why are you creating new branch for every commit? I could understand creating tags for them (if, for example, each snapshot represented numbered version), but not branches.

Comment: @svick I seem to be mistakenly committing too much lately... :) Answering your question, I am a git newbie coming from many years of CVS and creating a new branch is my way of `CVS tag`-ing them. The goal is to give each such commit a name so that I can identify it with the name of the snapshot I gave it back then. I don't think I will ever branch-off an older branch but so far, this has been working great for me. I am always happy to learn a better way, however. +1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To just delete the commit you just made, assuming you are on the `master` branch, all you have to do is:

1. `git branch -D <name of the branch>` to delete the branch
2. `git reset --hard HEAD^` to reset the current branch to the previous commit and the working directory with it

After that, you can commit the forgotten directory normally and then the one you reset.

Comment: Perfect. I just verified this working perfectly for me, exactly as I intended. Thanks +1.

Comment: Interestingly, I didn't need a `git commit --amend`. Does that mean that the mistaken commit is still recorded somewhere in `.git`?

Comment: @WinWin, at first, git keeps *all* commits you make. So, when you use `git reset --hard`, the commit still exists, but is not reachable using normal methods. When using `git commit --amend`, the same happens: the old version still exists. To get the old versions, you can use reflog. Under default setting, entries in the reflog expire after 90 days. After that, the commit is going to be automatically deleted (or you can do it manually using `git gc`).